# awk procedure in bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have a task:
Write a script for the summation of integers stored in the file. Form a call script:
example: sum a.txt 3 4

The input file can contain several columns of integer. The individual columns are separeted be speces ora tabs. The script should sum a appropriate columns and write the result to stdout.
So when we have "sum a.txt 3 4" we need to add the number of the third and fourth columns file.

So i do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=( "$@" )
let LA=${#array1[@]}-1
awk '{for(i=1;i<=$LA;i++)y+=$'${array1[i]}'; print y}' a.txt
```

but i have an error: awk: : 1unexpected character '.'

Please help is there another way to add up the number of columns whose number are given in the procedure call script?

Comment: You can't cross shell/awk boundaries that way. Either use a shell loop and a shell array or push all the values to awk and use an awk array. (Run your script with `set -v` or `set -x` to see what is actually being run to see your current error.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing 3 arguments to sum

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v col1=$2 -v col2=$3 '{sum1 += $col1; sum2 += $col2} END{print sum1,sum2}' $1
```

when the script is invoked as `sum a.txt 3 4`, then

```
$1 = a.txt
$2 = 3
$4 = 4
```

**EDIT**

If the number of columns can vary

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
cols=${@:2:$#}

awk -v c="$cols" '{split(c, cols, " "); for (col in  cols) sum[col]+=$col} END{for (i in sum) print sum[i]}' $filename
```

**Explanation**

- `-v c="$cols"` creates an awk variable `c` and pass the column list
- `split(c, cols, " ")` split the column list `c` to obtain an array , cols
- `for (col in  cols) sum[col]+=$col` for each column value in `cols` array find the sum, `sum[col]+=$col`
- `END{for (i in sum) print sum[i]}` print the `sum` array

Comment: awk: line 2: missing } near end of file

Comment: @LucynaIlczuk sorry it was a typo. corrected in the answer

Comment: how do you run the script? are you using the newly edited answer as such. Because it works fine for me

Comment: i just write procedure "./suma a.txt 3 4" in terminal window

Comment: @LucynaIlczuk - you did something wrong when copying the script into your file. I suspect you have a spurious `'` left over from your original script but it could be something else. Do not try to re-type the script by hand. Copy/paste it exactly as-is from this site. If you still have a problem you're going to have to do some debugging yourself as the script posted here is perfectly correct as written.

Comment: @LucynaIlczuk i too think so because am getting the expected output

Comment: ok it works, but what if we don't know the amount of numbers of columns that will be given in the procedure example: ./sum a.txt 2 3 ... n (maybe i need use "for" but how?)

Comment: @LucynaIlczuk i have added an edit to include any number of columns. hope it helps